# Write double value to cell independent of culture

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I set the value of a cell in a spreadsheet using Excel COM Interop:

```
public void SetValue(double value, string sheetName, int cellRow, int cellColumn)
{
    var cell = GetCell(sheetName, cellRow, cellColumn);
    cell.Value2 = value;
}
```

`GetCell()` is a method returning the Range object.

Depending on the system culture settings, this method doesn't work properly:

These values:

[image]

are written as follows, if the culture of Excel is German:

[image]

My questions:

1. Why doesn't Excel handle the formatting properly? Isn't `Value2` "typesafe"?
2. How can I set the double value correctly independent of system culture?

Comment: Assigning a `double` to either `Value` or `Value2` will correctly work on all system cultures because it's an actual number as opposed to a textual representation. The fact that it displays differently/unexpectedly on the screen is completely unrelated. That would be a textual representation of the double, and it is set up separately.

Comment: Is the problem that you're seeing more decimal places (0.03615... rather than 0.04)?

Comment: @ChrisF Also the `0.03615`s were entered as strings. There is apparently another overload of `SetValue`.

Comment: @ChrisF: No, that's actually fine. The problem is the representation of the Youngs Modulus in Excel, for example.

Comment: @GSerg: Ok, so in general the way of setting the value is fine. There is an overload for SetValue(), taking a string ;) Well observed. It shouldn't be called, however, I'll investigate that. What do you mean: display and actual value are completely unrelated? Isn't the valiue showing up in Excel supposed to represent the underlying value?

Comment: @Marc *Represent* is the correct word. There is a binary value which is *the* value, and there is an infinite number of ways to print it on the screen in various formats. When you are working with actual values you should not be concerned with their possible textual representations, so the very question about `Value` supporting a culture is meaningless, `Value` does not have a concept of culture.

Comment: @GSerg: Ok, that makes sense. I'll try to find out about how to fix the representation, then. If you post your answer, I'll be happy to mark and upvote ;) Thank you!

Comment: @Mark First find out what and why you want to fix. It would appear that interface displays `Youngs Modulus` scaled to `10^10`. If so, and you want the same in Excel, you will have to divide the number by `10^10` before sending to Excel because with number formatting alone you [can scale to `10^9`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx#SpecifierTh) but not to `10^10`, and then you'd need keep in mind you have a wrong value in Excel. Or maybe you have a rouge `10^10` multiplication somewhere before sending to Excel, then just remove that.

Comment: @GSerg: I called the wrong overload of my set value method and passed a string :( Thank you for your help, impressing that you guessed right in your first comment already without knowing... Thank you!